# Jquery: change input text value on focusout

Tags: jquery, focusout

I have the field like below

[image]

input text is fixed to 11 digit.

Now When focus out I want the input text to be changed like below

> 123-456-789-01

how can I achive this using Jquery

can anyone guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex below to format your phone `phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4");` and set `maxlength`=11

```
$('#phone').focusout(function() {

  function phoneFormat() {
    phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4");
    return phone;
  }
  var phone = $(this).val();
  phone = phoneFormat(phone);
  $(this).val(phone);
});
```

```js
$('#phone').focusout(function() {

  function phoneFormat() {
    phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4");
    return phone;
  }
  var phone = $(this).val();
  phone = phoneFormat(phone);
  $(this).val(phone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="phone" maxlength="11"  />
```